# someExcel VBA: Cannot create a range object successfully

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first question here, so bear with me. I'm a security consultant working on a huge firewall migration, for which I got my VBA skill from under a thick layer of dust. So far I have managed to get all my issues resolved by searching, but this issue: I get errors when doing exactly how I find it everywhere.

What I want to do:
I have an array that contains (among other things), strings formatted like this: "A3:P59", representing a cell range. 
Now, this are ranges within a table. When I get the address of a certain cell in the table, I want to test if it's in that range.

I wrote a test function:

```
   Function TestCellRange() As Boolean  
    Dim tbl As ListObject  
    Dim cell, rng, test As range  
    Dim range As range

    Dim bRow, eRow As Integer

    Set tbl = shRulebase.ListObjects("tblBFFirewallRules")
    shRulebase.Activate
    With shRulebase

    cell = tbl.DataBodyRange(5, 1).Address(False, False) 'it's this command that gives me issues
    Set range = .range(.Cells(bRow, 1), .Cells(eRow, 16)) 

    Debug.Print cell
    'Set rng = shRulebase.range(range)
    Debug.Print rng

    Set test = Application.Intersect(cell, range(range(A3), range(P59)))
    If test Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("oops")
        TestCellRange = False

    Else
        MsgBox ("yup yup")
        TestCellRange = True
    End If
    End With

End Function
```

Now whatever I try, I keep getting blocked on the set range:

- **set range =  .Range("A3:P59")** -> will return "object required", on the "set test" line (if i use intersect (cell, range))
- **Set range = range("A3:P59")** -> will return object variable or with block variale not set on the same line
- **Set range = .range(.Cells(bRow, 1), .Cells(eRow, 16))** -> will step through, but debug.print returns a type mismatch and "Set test = Application.Intersect(cell, range)" returns a "object required"

Any help would be really appreciated...I'm all to familiar with networks ip's and the bits and bytes of it, but here I am a bit out of my comfort zone and I need to finish this by tomorrow :(

Greetings,
Kraganov

EDIT Some More tries:

- **rng and cell as variant:**
  cell = tbl.DataBodyRange(5, 1).Address(False, False)
  rng = .range("A3:P59").Address(False, False)
  Set test = Application.Intersect(cell, rng)
  ==>I would get objects required
- **just using rng as range and trying to set it without "set"**
  rng = .range("A3:P59")

EDIT 2 : I found a way around using the range.

So what I was trying to do, was the following:
I had a table that contains information about firewall rules. However, not every line describes a rule. There are also lines that described the context in which the rules below that line were to be placed. 
Outside of the table, aside of those lines there would be a cell with the range of cells for that context. I wanted to use that to describe the context for those rules, if I pulled them.
I ended up looping through the table rows and identifying those specific rows and setting a "context" variable when, a row like that was met.

Comment: First, naming variable same as type is not a good idea, IMHO. Second, in `Dim cell, rng, test As range`, only test is of type Range, cell and rng are of type Variant. In VBA you need to repeat `As type` for each variable.

Comment: true, naming is terrible.....it was just for a proof of concept function. :-)
The actual code would be more aptly named. 

Now, if I indeed decalred explicitly cell as range, it would fail. 
if I declared both rng and cell as variant and used the following:
cell = tbl.DataBodyRange(5, 1).Address(False, False)  
rng = .range("A3:P59").Address(False, False)  
Set test = Application.Intersect(cell, rng)  
I would get objects required

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the cell as well as following:

```
set cell = tbl.DataBodyRange(5, 1).Address(False, False)
```

What is cell? A Range?

Comment: yeah, sorry, tried making the formatting bit clearer. it does weird things.

So I can successfully set 'cell' as a range with the Address from a cell in the table, debug.print will print it as "A6" in this example.
However, no such thing seems to happen with the 'range' variable. 
If it gets set and I hover over it, it doesn't show anything and the debug.print will return "type mismatch"

Comment: in short :
cell is a range for a single cell: A6
Range is a real range: A3:P59

End goal is to find out if A6 exists in A3:P59 or not

Comment: by the way: i cannot set it as you said, as I need to use a string that refers to a cell range in the table

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add 'set' to the range value assignment.

Try just

range = .Range("A3:P59")

Comment: Also one of the many variations I tried. ==> Returns "object variable or with block variable not set"

Answer (score 0):

```
Function TestCellRange() As Boolean
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim cellToTest As Range
    Dim testResult As Range

    Set tbl = shRulebase.ListObjects("tblBFFirewallRules")
    Set cellToTest = tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(5, 1)
    'or with one more level of indirection
    'Set cellToTest = shRulebase.range(tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(5, 1).Value)         
    Set testResult = Application.Intersect(cellToTest, [A3:P59])
    If testResult Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("oops")
        TestCellRange = False
    Else
        MsgBox ("yup yup")
        TestCellRange = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: alass, that didn't work either. I think my VBA just getting freaky on me.

Comment: What error did you get? Because it worked fine on my side.

Comment: I just made a full copy now of your function rather than editing my own and got "The Item with the specified name wasn't found" on the line off application intersect

Comment: if I changed your line to "Set testResult = Application.Intersect(cellToTest, range("A3:P59"))" then the error is "Method 'intersect' of object_Application failed" (which is already further than I got before

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the post of VincentG I found the working solution. Thanks for that.

```
Function TestCellRange() As Boolean
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim cellToTest As range
Dim testResult As range

Set tbl = shRulebase.ListObjects("tblBFFirewallRules")
shRulebase.Activate
Set cellToTest = tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(5, 1)
'or with one more level of indirection
'Set cellToTest = shRulebase.range(tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(5, 1).Value)
Set testResult = Application.Intersect(cellToTest, range("A3:P59"))
If testResult Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("oops")
    TestCellRange = False
Else
    MsgBox ("yup yup")
    TestCellRange = True
End If
End Function
```